# Self-Registered via Customer Portal field on user object

Tags: customer-portal

We allow external portal users to login to via Self Register. But a new user is created the standard 'Self-Registered via Customer Portal' field is not get updated. This is not a writable field. How to update that field?

Comment: How user is being created ...? if it's not created through self registration page..it would be false

Comment: Yes, user created via self registration page.